# ¿Convertir una web en una app para android/ios?

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, phonegap

¿Es posible convertir web en una app para android/ios? 
¿Como se podría hacer?
¿Con apache cordova, con phonegap o de alguna otra forma? ¿Como podría añadir google cast y similares?

Answer (score 1):

Si conoces Angular pues usa ionic.
Si conoces Angular2 pues ionic2.
Si conoces c# pues usa xamarim.

Si connoces swift y android pues hazlas nativas.

Con todos ellos puedes convertir una web en una app especialmente con las 3 primeras.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchas posibilidades, usar por ejemplo Framework 7, PhoneGapp, OnsenUI, entre muchas otras.

Pero hay 2 variantes aquí si haces eso tu app será relativamente más lenta ya que deben pasarla a ejecutarse "nativamente" y 2, la página como tal no pasaría a ser app, si no que deberías cubrir ciertos lineamientos que solicitan los frameworks (básicamente reconstruir).

Si literalmente quieres que tu página que es responsiva pase a app sin modificar nada, lo único que se me ocurriría sería que uses un WebView a fullscreen en una app nativa y listo, así todo se mueve en esa WebView

Update 2021:
Ya puedes hacer webs más fácil para Android/iOS gracias a las Progressive Web Apps (PWA) únicamente investiga cómo se hacen y podrás soltarlas a las tiendas de forma más sencilla (no estoy 100% seguro para iOS, pero Android y la Microsoft Store en desktop incluso avalan PWA sin problema siempre y cuando cumplas los lineamientos solicitados)

Answer (score 0):

Si no dominas el desarrollo en android y objetive c te recomendaría usar cordova aunque es mas rápido ionic pues usa angular.
Estas tecnologías simulan ser aplicaciones pero al final son paginas encapsuladas con acceso a funciones de dispositivos android e ios.

Comment: Más que objetive yo diría Swift, ya que es el lenguaje que se utiliza actualmente.